# ssh-keyscan doesn't collect ec2 instance public keys in GitLab job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, continuous-delivery

I work on GitLab ci/cd pipeline that should deploy docker containers to AWS ec2 instance. I'm trying to implement approach described [here](https://www.fosstechnix.com/gitlab-ci-deploy-to-ec2-using-ssh/) and one of my jobs is being failed because `ssh-keyscan <ip>` doesn't work.
My pipeline looks like that:

```
...
deploy-to-staging:
    image: docker:20.10.14
    stage: deploy to staging
    needs: ["docker-stuff"]
    before_script:
        - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
        - ssh-keyscan $EC2_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
...
```

It fails at `- ssh-keyscan $EC2_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` line with `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`.

My GitLab varables:

- SSH_PRIVATE_KEY - EC2 key-pair private key of .pem format
- EC2_IP - Public IPv4 DNS

I've tried `ssh-keyscan <ipv4 DNS or IP>` locally and it works. I've also tried it on separate ubuntu ec2 instance and it has no output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had wrong outbound rules in aws security group. I've changed SSH IP to 0.0.0.0/0 and it have worked. Hope this will help someone.